# Are you allowed to ask follow-up questions or duplicate questions if there were no satisfactory answers?

Tags: support, questions, exact-duplicates

Are things like follow-up questions or duplicate questions if there were no satisfactory answers, permissible on this site?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. If its your own question, a bounty is the right way, assuming you have the reputation. If you want to add more helpful, relevant details, go ahead (Thats to say, don't edit to bump. Edit to include more relevant information).

If its a related tangential question, *sufficiently distinct* to warrant its own question, you can refer back to the old one, but if you're trying to get attention by re-asking, no, thats not the best way to do it

Comment: Okay, thank you for clarifying the rules.

Comment: @JoshZmijewski A good (tactical) edit can often be in the form of re-writing the title. The more descriptive unique words that flow together and describe your problem, the better. Helps to guarantee that the ideal person sees it.

Comment: If it's another user's question, a bounty can help as well.